# A theme editor for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, gui

In Windows settings users can make simple combinations of colours and photos.

Yet there is much more potential, when editing .theme files directly. There was a kickstarter project "Customatic", trying to create a theme-editor, but it seems that was given up.

I am looking for a dedicated editor, ideally with a GUI which gives live previews as the file (or theme pack) is being edited.

I am aware that any text editor can be used to edit some definitions but there are many things to be considered. For example how to generate a valid new theme id like this:  `ThemeId={885FBC04-A22E-49A6-9450-07E30B2AC6BC}`

My motivation is not to make yet-another pretty-pack (there are hundreds for free download on the MS Store, I know). I need to get an old paid installation of CorelDraw hacked to make it useable on Windows 10. This is about contrast, an aspect not available via Windows Personalization. When I manually tweaked some themes, I badly damaged my Windows (start menu and start button gone). So I would muchly appreciate a dedicated editor with some inbuilt know-how.

Plan B:

If nothing is out there, I would like to find syntax highlighting definitions for .theme files (for mainstream editors like Notepad++ or Sublime Text 3 or Kate). Or more documentation please.

If you want to know more about what is involved, have a look here:
[This (Microsoft) document discusses the format of Theme (.theme) files.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/themesfileformat-overview#creating-a-theme-file)

Although the user who gave me that link states:

> ... clearly not written for Windows 10 because not all of the attributes are the same, and even then not everything is explained completely

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling high contrast themes in Ease of Access Settings (Settings > Ease of Access > High Contrast)?

Also, [these themes](https://www.howtogeek.com/133405/how-to-get-classic-style-themes-back-on-windows-8/), inspired by the old Windows Classic themes, might also help.

Also, probably less useful to you is [Open Shell](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu/releases) (based on [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net)), which allows for extensive Start Menu and Taskbar customization, as well as bringing some older features back to Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Yes, I have tried "high contrast". I would make the Corel menu visible - but would give me brain-cancer in one afternoon. I cannot concentrate and do meaningful graphic-work in Corel, when my entire Windows goes zombie-contrast. That is why hacking the theme will allow just to tweak one detail - it even worked until my machine stopped responding to the start menu. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the link to "these themes" where I found this information: "Note that High Contrast Themes use a different engine – they allow you to select different colors for different interface elements, while the standard Windows 8 themes only allow you to select a single color." Which I will persue if no full answer will come up here. So I give you +1 for useful input and say thanks.